# TextChange Event is triggered with Delay on windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i trigger a form from an other form when i click a button. The new form is loaded succesfully. Also note that the new form has textbox and a button. I am checking the length of text entered on **TextChangeEvent** of textbox. However, i face a delay of minimum 30 sec to more than 2 mins sometimes when i try to enter text in textbox and during that time the whole form is unresponsive. Also this happen only for the first time after that it works smoothly. Below is the code:

**Form1:**

```
 frmPasswortAbfr.Initialisieren(False, lArchiv)
 Meldungen.Log(9, "frmMain.PasswrdFrm Initialized" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
 If frmPasswortAbfr.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
         Meldungen.Log(9, "frmMain.PasswrdFrm password ok" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
 End If
```

**Form2 (frmPasswortAbfr):**

```
Friend Sub Initialisieren(ByVal pErsteEingabe As Boolean, ByVal pArchiv As Core.ArchivBes)
    Try
        Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd Initialisieren Entered" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
        mArchiv = pArchiv
        mErsteEingabe = pErsteEingabe
        Me.Text = mResources.GetString("ArchivbereichEntsperren") & " - " & mArchiv.Name
        If pErsteEingabe Then
            lblInfoText.Visible = True
            pnlBackground.Location = New Point(-3, 50)
            txtKennwortWdh.Visible = True
            lblPasswortWdh.Visible = True
            lblPasswort.Location = New Point(12, 107)
            txtKennwort.Location = New Point(12, 126)
            lblInfoText.Text = My.Resources.AlleSeitenUndDokumenteInDiesemArchivbereichWerdenMitEinemPersoenlichenKennwortVerschluesselt
            lblInfoFett.Text = My.Resources.BitteMerkenSieSichDiesesKennwortUnbedingt
            lblInfoNormal.Text = My.Resources.IhreDatenGehenAnsonstenVerloren
            lblFehlerMeldung.Text = My.Resources.DieKennwoerterStimmenNichtUeberein
            btnAbbrechen.Location = New Point(237, 227)
            btnSpeichern.Location = New Point(143, 227)
            btnSpeichern.Text = My.Resources.Speichern
            lblFehlerMeldung.Location = New Point(34, 205)
            picFehlerIcon.Location = New Point(12, 202)
            picHinweis.Image = My.Resources.warning24
            Me.Height = 298
        Else
            lblInfoText.Visible = False
            pnlBackground.Location = New Point(-3, 0)
            txtKennwortWdh.Visible = False
            lblPasswortWdh.Visible = False
            lblPasswort.Location = New Point(12, 57)
            txtKennwort.Location = New Point(12, 76)
            lblInfoFett.Text = My.Resources.DieserArchivbereichIstGesperrt
            lblInfoNormal.Text = My.Resources.BitteGebenSieIhrPersoenlichesKennwortEin
            lblFehlerMeldung.Text = My.Resources.DasKennwortIstNichtRichtig
            btnAbbrechen.Location = New Point(237, 127)
            btnSpeichern.Location = New Point(143, 127)
            btnSpeichern.Text = My.Resources.Entsperren
            lblFehlerMeldung.Location = New Point(34, 105)
            picFehlerIcon.Location = New Point(12, 102)
            picHinweis.Image = My.Resources.lock24
            Me.Height = 198
            Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd Initialisieren End" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Assert(False)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSpeichern_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSpeichern.Click
    Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd btnSpeichern_Click Entered" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
    If mErsteEingabe Then
        If Not txtKennwort.Text = txtKennwortWdh.Text Then
            lblFehlerMeldung.Visible = True
            picFehlerIcon.Visible = True
            txtKennwortWdh.Refresh()
        Else
            Try
                mArchiv.SetSchluessel(txtKennwort.Text)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Assert(False)
            End Try

            DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Else
        Try
            mArchiv.SetSchluessel(txtKennwort.Text)
            DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Me.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblFehlerMeldung.Visible = True
            picFehlerIcon.Visible = True
            txtKennwort.Refresh()
        End Try
        Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd btnSpeichern_Click end" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmPasswortAbfr_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd frmPasswortAbfr_Load Entered" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
    lblFehlerMeldung.Visible = False
    picFehlerIcon.Visible = False
    ' txtKennwort.Text = ""
    ' txtKennwortWdh.Text = ""
    btnSpeichern.Enabled = False
    Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd frmPasswortAbfr_Load end" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
End Sub

Private Sub txtKennwort_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtKennwort.TextChanged
    Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd txtKennwort_TextChanged Entered" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
    If Not mErsteEingabe Then btnSpeichern.Enabled = txtKennwort.Text <> ""
    Meldungen.Log(9, "frmPasswrd txtKennwort_TextChanged end" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "MyTestFunction")
End Sub
```

Below is the log file entries:
.
.
.

**25.01.2018 12:45:25   9   MyTestFunction  frmPasswrd frmPasswortAbfr_Load....**

---

**25.01.2018 12:45:55 MyTestFunction    frmPasswrd txtKennwort_TextChanged Entered...**
25.01.2018 12:45:55 MyTestFunction  frmPasswrd txtKennwort_TextChanged end...
.
.

As you see there is 30 sec delay. I am not sure what might be causing this any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's odd that you call `frmPasswortAbfr.Initialisieren(False, lArchiv)`.  Normally that kind of stuff would be passed through the form's constructor.  The Load event only happens once, but it looks like you pre-loaded the form somewhere.  Where do you create the form?

Comment: @LarsTech  i am not sure whether i understand you question but frmPasswortAbfr is friend class so i access its element and set it to required value and form is created when the showdialog is called. this is all done in Form1. I hope i answer your question correclty

Comment: Where in your code do you create frmPasswortAbfr?  Do you show the form previously?

Comment: Nop this is the first time i am calling the frmPasswortAbfr

Comment: I don't see `new frmPasswortAbfr` so you aren't showing us everything.

Comment: What i know showdialog() will create a form instance by itself. you can see the same in this :[showdialog-without-form-instance](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b18e4c86-0d7e-48d6-b5b5-bf26750d9dee/showdialog-without-form-instance?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs)

Comment: I endorse the answer in that link.  Move your initialize code to a constructor and then use a using block: `Using fp As New frmPasswortAbfr(False, lArchiv)`